# Can we mmap /dev/mem to supply expected output for dmidecode inside a container

Tags: linux

The tool `dmidecode` relies on `/dev/mem`. However, most Docker containers do not have `/dev/mem` attached during container spawning. Therefore, most containers do not have `/dev/mem`. The `mknod` can create character special file `/dev/mem` inside the container. Further more, I can dump my computer's SMBIOS into a binary file. I also just quick scan/read in google and saw that `mmap` is possible between a special character file and a normal file.

Can `dmidecode` inside the container be fooled in this way? I ask to more understand add context of this idea although, the core ingredients seemed to be all present.

So the question is: Can we hijack the container's `/dev/mem` by feeding it with a binary dump of the host's smbios? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I misread your question. I'm still not sure why you're looking to `mmap`, though, because you can accomplish what I think you're asking without that.

That is, if I create a dump of `/dev/mem` on my host:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mem of=/tmp/mem.dump
```

Then I can bind mount that into a container:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /tmp/mem.dump:/dev/mem alpine sh
```

And run something like `dmidecode` inside the container:

```
/ # dmidecode
# dmidecode 3.2
Scanning /dev/mem for entry point.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
90 structures occupying 4101 bytes.
Table at 0x000EC470.

Handle 0xDA00, DMI type 218, 251 bytes
...
```

And in fact you can just copy the file into place:

```
/ # dmidecode
# dmidecode 3.2
Scanning /dev/mem for entry point.
/dev/mem: No such file or directory
/ # cp /tmp/mem.dump /dev/mem
/ # dmidecode
# dmidecode 3.2
Scanning /dev/mem for entry point.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
90 structures occupying 4101 bytes.
Table at 0x000EC470.

Handle 0xDA00, DMI type 218, 251 bytes
...
```